AWS DMS doesn't support the BOOLEAN data type in your source Db2 LUW database
I'm doing migration from DB2 LUW to Aurora PostgreSQL using AWS DWS
Source - IBM DB2 LUW
Target - Aurora PostgreSQL
AWS DMS doesn't support the BOOLEAN data type in your source Db2 LUW database.
Due to this we are seeing mismatched records in AWS DMS validation.
What is our next steps.
Run the below command in target Aurora PostgreSQL database and see the difference like below.
select * from public.awsdms_validation_failures_v1;
[[{'XXXXX': ''}, {'XXXXX': '0'}],

Have you asked the supplier of AWS DWS? Don't they have a support channel?
